# can I add a key to firebase database?

Tags: javascript, rest, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to add a KEY to firebase database?

While adding data to the DB, it generates a random key. But is it possible have my own key and then add data inside it.

Comment: Did you search before you asked? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+custom+key

Comment: Hi Saumya, welcome to SO. Your question is not currently containing enough information to understand what you are asking. Please read the [SO guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) carefully, they are a good guide for beginners. It will help you draft your question in a better format to garner appropriate answers.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling will keep that in mind.

Comment: Hi @HazardouS thanks for the tips. Well, I am trying to make a custom key in the DB and then check null for the first time. Currently its generating a random key for the data I want to save, so checking for null becomes very difficult.

Comment: @saumya Post your code

Comment: Found the solution. 
**Firebase does not provide a way to add just a key. If there is no data, there is no key**

So I fixed it by checking the data to be null first. Then while adding the data, I prefixed the url with the desired key like


`firebaseProjectURI/userid/MyDesiredKey/{data}`

Hope that helps someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

hello there and welcome to Stackoverflow, yes you can put your own key like you want, just be sure that the key is not duplicated. or you can try this:

```
var ref = mRef.push();
var key = ref.key;
```

Comment: hi @oussema-aroua thanks. I got it working. Please have a look to my comments above, let me know if there is a better way.